# How to launch parallel http request inside a thread group in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a thread group, under thread group I have several request. I want to run all the requests in parallel that is the user access the requests in parallel.

Comment: If the requests are interdependent then it is not possible, otherwise put each request in a separate thread group.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you can always create different thread groups per request and disable "Run thread groups consecutively" in Test Plan.

However, I am not sure how to setup a common thread group thread properties other than externalizing these parameters to Global Variables.